# Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Visible is always returning false

Tags: excel, vba, c#-4.0, vsto, excel-addins

I trying to find out the visibility of the Excel and do some activities based on it. But these  two are always returning false.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Visible

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Visible
```

Any ideas why it is always false? I removed all my Excel addins in my machine and then created a brand new one and still it is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I remember this issue for Word 2010 as well. It was filed as a bug long time ago and I am not sure if it has been rectified. If you have access to this link, then please see this.

**Topic**: VSTO add-in for Word 2010 shows Application.Visible = False in ThisAddIn_Startup()

**Link**: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541094/vsto-add-in-for-word-2010-shows-application-visible-false-in-thisaddin-startup

This behavior however is not seen in Word 2007. If you want, you can check with Excel 2007 and see if that is the case.

**FOLLOWUP**

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Not that I am aware of but there can be an alternative. BTW did you check it for Excel 2007? Does it show true?

Comment: No, I don't have development environment for Excel 2007

Comment: Lemme get hold of a machine with Excel 2007 and then test it with VS 2008/2010/2012. Will get back to you in a day or two...

Comment: BTW, if you have a small sample of the project handy then I will not have to recreate it and I can test it for you...

Comment: I just got a simple message box to test this MessageBox.Show(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Visible.ToString());

Comment: Ok I checked it in Excel 2007 + VS 2008. It gives me `True`. I just remembered that I had both in my virtual machine. :) In Excel 2010/VS 2010, it gives me false so yes, it is a bug :)

Comment: Thank you very much for finding this out for me.

Comment: I would be uploading a screenshot for both very soon :)